# Multiple zeros and differentiability of $h$ such that $f(x) = (x-a)^k h(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

> Let $f \in \mathcal{C}^{k+1}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f^{(p)}(a) = 0$, $p = 0,1,2 \cdots, k-1$,
> and $f^{(k)}(a) \neq 0 $ and $f(x) = (x-a)^k h(x)$. Is it true that $h \in \mathcal{C}^{k+1}(\mathbb{R})$?

**My attempt:**

From the Taylor expansion:
$$f(x) = \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k
+ \frac{f^{(k+1)}(\eta)}{(k+1)!}(x-a)^{k+1} $$

where $\eta = \eta(x)$ is between $x$ and $\alpha$. Taking $h(x) = \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}
+ \frac{f^{(k+1)}(\eta)}{(k+1)!}(x-a)$, then $h$ is not necessarily differentiable since we don't nothing about $\eta(x)$, besides that it lies in $[x,a]$ or $[a,x]$.

Am I right?
Could someone show a concrete example that shows that $h$ is not differentiable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Will M. : Why not? This is Taylor's expansions using that $f^{(p)}(a) = 0$ for $p=0,1, \cdots, k-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO. More precisely,  you can only be sure that $h \in \mathcal{C}^1$ but not $\mathcal{C}^2$.

Counter example is in the following:
$$f(x)= |x|^{5/2}+x, \quad k=1, \quad a=0$$